# PHP - Undefined index - $_POST hidden input

Tags: php, html

I'm a beginner at coding, and I have to make a small game in php for school. 
I have to use a hidden input, like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="rand" value="<?php rand(1,10); ?>" />
</form>
```

The value stands for a random number between 1 and 10 (I hope the value is correct). Now, in process.php I want to retrieve the random number by using post, so what I tried to do is the following:

```
<?php $random = $_POST['rand'];
echo $random; ?>
```

In my browser (Firefox), I'm getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: rand in
>   G:\xampp\htdocs\process.php on line 2

Does anyone know how I can echo the hidden value without using complex techniques?

Thanks in advance,
Maxime

Comment: hidden inputs only get processed *after* the form was submitted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Is your form also in `process.php`? If yes, then is this error message on initial page load?

Comment: no, I only echoed the hidden value in process.php, and the error was on the initial page load

Answer (score 1):

You haven't echoed your rand function within the hidden input tag.

Also, there should be a submit button. Only then you can access the POST parameters.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rand" value="<?php echo rand(1,10); ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Try something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_POST); // See your POST array
   $random = $_POST['rand'];
   echo $random;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: I think you made a small mistake there ;) "<pre"> instead of "<pre>". But anyway, thanks a lot!